# Searching repository for plugin struts2-archetype-blank for m2Eclipse

Tags: repository, m2eclipse

i'm Searching repository for plugin struts2-archetype-blank for m2Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

search.maven.org is a service provided by Sonatype so as to provide a reliable resource for maven artifacts. You can search for your plugin here.